# RNN Biases & Weights

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I have not been able to find a concrete answer on the following questions yet. Any information that I come across online is either incomplete, ambiguous, or contradicts what another source says.

Assuming you have a Recurrent Neural Network that uses biases on the input layer and all hidden layers:

1. do biases have weights just like any other node on the respective layer, or is the raw value used in calculating the next layer's activation function(s)?

If the former is true:

2. during back-propagation, are you adjusting the *weights* associated with the previous layer's bias, or are you adjusting the *value* of the bias itself.

For question #2, I'm assuming that it's the former and the value of the bias never actually changes from its initial value.

Comment: I think you might find contradicting information because your question is full of misconceptions. Biases ARE weights, so they are adjusted using backpropagation. Your second question makes no sense, each layer adjusts its own bias. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Okay. Is the bias for a particular layer a vector or a single value?

Comment: Generally it is a vector.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy thank you for your responses. You have, indeed, clarified a lot of my misconceptions. If you would like to reiterate your comments in the form of an answer I would happily give you it a green check mark.